# how to convert a graph from visNetwork to plotly

Tags: r, plotly, visnetwork

I want to know if there is any possibility to convert a `visNetwork` graph to `plotly` graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visNetwork` object has an element called `x`, which stores nodes, edges and some other information. Using that, you could - in theory - [rebuild the graph using `plotly`](https://plot.ly/r/network-graphs/).